# Bower: Command not found

Tags: linux, node.js, bower

I'm struggling trying to install Bower. 
I alredy installed Bower with this command : [$ sudo npm install -g bower]
But when I try to check with: "bower --help" it says that the command is not found.
I tried to add "/usr/local/bin/npm" to my PATH doing: [$ export PATH="/usr/local/bin/npm:$PATH"]
but it is still not working.

Any idea ?

Thankkkssss

Answer (score 0):

As far as `npm` is a binary you should not add it to your $PATH. $PATH only contains directories which contains binaries.
If you have `locate` installed you can try to find the binary with `locate bower` and then add the path to the directory which contains the binary to your $PATH. There is also a chance that the binary of Bower is not called `bower`, so check the documentation.